# eBPF vs. System vs. DTrace

Tags: dtrace, bpf, ebpf

Which one is the main one going to be supported by CentOS going forward?

I am not an expert at any of these tools, so I would like to know which one I should learn much deeper.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SystemTap or `stap` might be the one you want to try. Also checkout Brendan Gregg's blog. You will learn a lot there: http://www.brendangregg.com/overview.html